Jetpack DataStore native lib is added to bundle: libdatastore_shared_counter.so - what is that?
Recently I noticed that in new projects where I use Jetpack Datastore I have a new native lib added to apps' bundle:
bundle.abb\base\lib\arm64-v8a\libdatastore_shared_counter.so
What is that exactly?
and yeah I didn't have it previously with:
androidxDataStore = "1.0.0"
but got it after updating to:
androidxDataStore = "1.1.0"
update:
the issue here that now Google Play Console shows me a warning about debug symbols:

I tried to add
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        ...
        release {
            ...
            ndk {
                debugSymbolLevel = "FULL"
            }
        }
    }

as described here
But it didn't change anything...

FYI: Here is the source code of the .so file: https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/datastore/datastore-core/src/androidMain/cpp/shared_counter.cc

This appears to be related to: androidx/datastore/multiprocess/SharedCounter.kt, which may provide backend access control. See androidx.datastore.core, for example DataStoreImpl<T>:
/**
 * If downstream flow is UnInitialized, no data has been read yet, we need to trigger a new
 * read then start emitting values once we have seen a new value (or exception).
 *
 * If downstream flow has a ReadException, there was an exception last time we tried to read
 * data. We need to trigger a new read then start emitting values once we have seen a new
 * value (or exception).
 *
 * If downstream flow has Data, we should start emitting from downstream flow as long as its
 * version is not stale compared to the version read from the shared counter when we enter
 * the flow.
 *
 * If Downstream flow is Final, the scope has been cancelled so the data store is no
 * longer usable. We should just propagate this exception.
 *
 * State always starts at null. null can transition to ReadException, Data or
 * Final. ReadException can transition to another ReadException, Data or Final.
 * Data can transition to another Data or Final. Final will not change.
 */

The name multiprocess just doesn't align with the definition of "multiprocessing", which involves multiple processors - because in reality, it doesn't matter on which processor a forked thread runs.

the problem here that right now I have a warning from Google Play Console about native debug symbols, I tried to add android.buildTypes.release.ndk.debugSymbolLevel = "FULL" but it didn't help (see updated question)

but yeah, it's quite a different issue (about native symbols) - different question.

When building the library as module, it should generate relevant debug symbols - else they're simple not there.  Property android.buildTypes.release.ndk.debugSymbolLevel is in fact useless while not building from source. They're even supposed to have these debug symbols already. Maybe contact support?
